# How to merge commits from branches in specific order

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I had a git repo with `c1` as the head commit. As I had to work on two features simultaneously, I had do create a branch (`my branch`). I kept working on one feature and its sub-features in `main branch` and another feature in `my branch`. This is how my local repo looks like.

```
c0->c1->c3->c4->c5->c6 (main branch)
    \
     c2 (my branch)
```

All new commits from `main branch` have already been pushed to remote repo. Now feature `c2` is complete, and it must be merged with the `main branch`. This is how my local repo should look like.

```
c0->c1->c3->c4->c5->c6->c2
```

How to obtain this structure? `git cherry-pick` c2 fails throwing merge conflicts.

Comment: Did you try resolving those merge conflicts? Give what you've said you want, I don't think you have much choice.

Comment: I am more worried about the order. Will cherry-pick ensure that c2 comes after c6? Or will it try to enter it between c1 and c2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take care of the conflict and you should be fine. Conflicts are part of our work. Same thing would happen if you tried to merge, for example.

Comment: What about the order? If I solve conflicts, will c2 come after c5?

Comment: I guess you would be working on _main branch_ (poiting on c6 at the moment) and you would cherry-pick c2. That will bring c2 _after_ c6. It's **not** like git analyzes the time when c2 was created to magically insert it before c3, for example. It will put c2 on top of c6. Technically speaking, it's not really c2, it's an _equivalent_ of c2 (normally referred to as _c2'_ on documents around). It will keep the same author as c2, but committer will be the person who cherry-picks.

Comment: ... and it is a completely different revision from c2.

Answer (score 2):

If there are more than 1 commit you better use rebase, not cherry-pick:

`git rebase c1 c2 --onto main_branch`

Conflicts are still possible, of course. Resolve them during rebase; git prints a help when it stops at conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you perform this with `git merge`...

On master:

```
git merge c2
```

You then resolve conflicts at the point of merging.  Given how far back `c2` is in the history, and depending on what `c2` touched, conflicts are likely.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve as follows:

```
git checkout my_branch
git rebase master
<resolve any conflicts>
git checkout master
git merge my_branch
```